# Rendering after ajax request

Tags: vue.js

I have `place` objects that look like this:

```
"london" : {
  capital: true,
  images: ["pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg"],
  ...
}
```

They are retrieved from the backend and assigned to a `place` object in `data`.

**The issue/question I have is how to handle the delay in retrieving the data from the backend when rendering the view.**

My template might have something like this:

```
<p>{{place.images[0]}}</p>
```

but this causes errors/warnings in the console because there is no such thing as the images array until the data has been fetched.

I can think of two ways to handle this.

1. I define an empty images array within the data object. But I would have to do this for every property (and sub-property) that I will potentially use which isn't ideal.
2. I use `v-if` and a `loading` variable to conditionally render the template part.

Is there a "vuejs" approach to this that I've not considered?

Comment: #2 is the way to go. You shouldn't be trying to render data items that do not exist, and you shouldn't set dummy data items just to cover up the errors that would otherwise arise.

Comment: Decade is right, 2nd option is good and vue way.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for **The `v-cloak` directive**

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue
> instance finishes compilation.

You have to use like

```
<p v-cloak>{{place.images[0]}}</p>
```

Read about [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) in docs, and [more discussion](http://vuetips.com/v-cloak-directive-hides-html-on-startup)

Comment: I don't think so - this won't help with ajax data.

Comment: Your second option is vue based `I use v-if and a loading variable to conditionally render the template part.` then what you want ?